# JavaFX - Get Rid of `CustomMenuItem` blue highlight?

Tags: java, css, javafx

I have been struggling to remove a blue highlight from a `ContextMenu` implementation when it is hovered over.

[image]

```
private void attachContextMenu() {
    CustomMenuItem item = FilterPanel.getInMenuItem(this);
    ContextMenu contextMenu = new ContextMenu();
    contextMenu.getItems().add(item);


    tableColumn.setContextMenu(contextMenu);
}
```

With the containing `VBox` I was able to paint it white and get rid of a majority of the blue flash.

```
filterVBox.setStyle("-fx-background-color: white;");
```

But i cannot figure out how to get the `CustomerMenuItem` to lose the blue border when focused with the mouse.I tried the following but it does not work

```
CustomMenuItem item = FilterPanel.getInMenuItem(this);
item.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: white;");
```

Here is the [PR](https://bitbucket.org/controlsfx/controlsfx/pull-requests/579/making-improvements-to-minimize-blue/diff) if you want the full picture, but does anybody have an idea how I can manipulate that to go away?

I was able to get it to go away by styling every `MenuItem` for the entire `TableView` with this CSS. But I'd like to apply it specifically to *just* that `CustomMenuItem`.

```
.menu-item:focused {
   -fx-background-color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: Is it not an option to give you table a class and do ".table .menu-item:focused {..}"?

Comment: Have you tried to figure out from which element causes the highlight with [ScenicView](http://fxexperience.com/scenic-view/)? From the [style description](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#contextmenu) the contextmenu is a composite control.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the blue highlight happens when the ContextMenu gets the focus, you are dealing here with a [Pseudoclass](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/css/PseudoClass.html). In CSS, a pseudo-class is used to define a specific state of a node. Typical states are hover, selected, focused...

The way to deal with this is by adding a CSS file, where you can easily apply your style settings to any of the possible states.

First, apply a style class to your `ContextMenu` (so other controls using context menus don't get affected by these settings). For instance, `column-filter`:

```
private void attachContextMenu() {
    CustomMenuItem item = FilterPanel.getInMenuItem(this);

    ContextMenu contextMenu = new ContextMenu();
    contextMenu.getStyleClass().add("column-filter");

    contextMenu.getItems().add(item);
    tableColumn.setContextMenu(contextMenu);
}
```

Then add the required styling rules to a css file:

**style.css**

```
.column-filter .context-menu {
    -fx-background-color: white;
}

.column-filter .context-menu:focused {
    -fx-background-color: white;
}

.column-filter .custom-menu-item {
    -fx-background-color: white;
    -fx-padding: 0;
}

.column-filter .custom-menu-item:focused {
    -fx-background-color: white;
}
```

Finally you need to apply this stylesheet to the scene:

```
scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("style.css").toExternalForm());
```

And you'll get rid of the highlight.

[image: TableFilter]

Comment: Awesome. Worked perfectly thank you. Since the API does not have direct access to the `Scene` in which it is used, it does have access to the `TableView` so I added the CSS sheet to that control.

Comment: And thanks for going through the trouble of cloning this.

Comment: No problem, I've already had ControlsFX cloned! Yes, the logical way will be adding `tablefilter.css` to ControlsFX resources, and loading it by default on the `TableFilter` constructor: `tableView.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("/org/controlsfx/control/tablefilter.css").toExternalForm());`

Comment: I just put in a PR, and linked here to credit you. Thanks! https://bitbucket.org/controlsfx/controlsfx/pull-requests/580/blue_highlight_fix/diff

Comment: Thanks, now you can remove the `setStyle()` call from code as well.